# Interacting with bootbox modals with Capybara-Webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webkit, capybara-webkit, bootbox

Gem versions: Rails 4.1.14.rc2, Capybara 2.5.0, capybara-webkit 1.7.1

Our application is using bootbox modals to express soft validations for certain inputs. I am trying to use the `accept_confirm` with block method to capture the modal before Webkit automatically accepts it like so:

```
modal = accept_confirm do
  fill_in " Date of birth", with: "12/31/2015"
  click_on "Update Spouse"
end

expect(modal).to # have some sort of message
```

I receive this error in response:

```
 Failure/Error: modal = accept_confirm do
 Capybara::ModalNotFound:
   Timed out waiting for modal dialog
```

Does anybody have any experience using Webkit with bootbox modals?

***** UPDATE WITH SOLUTION *****

This was a race condition. Webkit moves faster than bootbox and it wasn't using capybara's wait time for some reason.  Adding a `sleep 0.5` after the event that triggers the bootbox modal allows the test to run properly. See example below:

```
fill_in " Date of birth", with: "12/31/2015"
click_on "Add benefit"
sleep 0.5

expect(page).to have_content "some warning message..."
click_on "Make Correction"

sleep 0.5
fill_in " Date of birth", with: "12/31/1905"
click_on "Add benefit"

sleep 0.5
expect(page).to have_content "some warning message..."
click_on "Make Correction"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Capybara modal API is for interacting with system modals  -- generated by calling window.alert/confirm/prompt in JS --  bootbox modals aren't system modals, they're just standard html elements.  You interact with them like any other element on a page.

Comment: Alright, that was very helpful, thank you! As it turns out, the reason I am using Webkit (its speed) was what was causing the problem.  The bootbox modal fade in was moving too slow so I had to tell webkit to slow down with a few `sleep 0.5`

Comment: @JakeKaad it's usually easier to just disable animations in test mode (remove the fade class or via JavaScript) since it causes a lot of flakiness for some drivers